# Invoke debugger while running program in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How to step into running a python program (in my case code which is already deployed to production), this issue is as follows, we are facing a specific functional issue, where one particular flow(lets call it Update to database flow) is resulting in an undesirable outcome.

We have 2 weeks deployment scheduled, only on critical cases, we have different schedules to be maintained.

i was looking for any specific modules(which could be handled through code) that cann be used for both python 2.x and python 3.x versions.

**NOTE**

This question was asked keeping in mind that the solution would/can be used in any running python code keeping 2.x and 3.x in mind, hence, was not very specific on one aspect of the code, as debugging is a common approach.

Comment: FWIW, you are likely to get a downvote or 2 on most sites if it looks like you've done no prior research on your question, especially if your rep or profile indicates that you aren't a beginner. Putting `python docs debugger` or `python docs breakpoint` into Google brings  up several relevant links.

Comment: Understood, now, how do I improve the current question? So that the downvoting can stop.  Since, the downvoting is not stopping. Btw , I have lost around 12 points already. Felling kinda depressed, since yesterday.

Comment: Well, you could edit into your question the info you learned from your prior research. That *might* help, but of course I can't promise anything.

Comment: Sure, I shall do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug by adding breakpoints in the code.

for python3.7+:

```
    breakpoint()
```

for python3.6 and below:

```
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: thanks, what about 2.7?

Comment: pdb works in 2.7